# What, if any, have been the consequences of the reveal in the "Warriors" cinematic?

Tags: league-of-legends

In 2020, a *League of Legends* cinematic was released to the tune of the song "Warriors," showing several separate battles (e.g. Caitlyn and Vi taking on Urgot in Zaun). This video seems to tie into events that have occurred in the lore, and thus appears to fit into the game canon. Specifically, Sylas appears to be assaulting a northern Demacian fortress with the help of Freljord soldiers, following up on the alliance forged in "The Shackles of Belief." Lux is there, seemingly waiting for the return of her brother Garen as he flees from Sylas's forces.

It is not so surprising that she would have been able to get in the fortress with the Demacian soldiers, since as of the end of the comic *Lux*, the general belief seems to be that she was merely manipulated by Sylas and bears no real responsibility for his escape. However, the scene shown in the video, where she (a member of the Crownguard and tasked with protecting a king who has vowed war against mages) calls down a pillar of light while fighting Sylas to help save Garen, would presumably raise a few eyebrows among the soldiers behind her in magic-hostile Demacia, even if they were not foolish enough to take issue with it in the midst of the battle.

What were the consequences of Lux openly revealing her powers in the midst of the Demacian soldiers? Have they been explored or mentioned in any further media?

Comment: The extent of it might be that Bob, a soldier behind her, did raise an eyebrow, but lowered it again after seeing how many of the enemy were slaughtered?

Comment: @SillybutTrue - What I mean is that if dozens of Demacian soldiers were aware (once Galio joined the fight, Sylas would have been outnumbered three champions to one, two if Vrynna was also there, and would not likely have been able to take the fortress), her secret would almost certainly have gotten back to the ears of the king and the mageseekers.